# Can we copy the results of an executed stored procedure data into temp table directly?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I tried using this

```
select * into #tempdb  (
exec SSC.usp_abc_data '01/31/2017','L','G','1','17',Null)
```

It prompts out an error saying that

> ```
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Comment: Its not a duplicate it looks like similar but not@paul Abbott

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like so:

```
SELECT * INTO #TestTableT FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC    [databasename].[schemaname].[sp name]')
-- Select Table
SELECT *
FROM #TestTableT;
```

so in your case it will be like:

```
SELECT * INTO  #tempdb FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC    [databasename].SSC.usp_abc_data ''01/31/2017'',''L'',''G'',''1'',''17'',Null')
-- Select Table
SELECT *
FROM #tempdb;
```

Just remember to include the database name.

if you are getting error in this method enable ad hoc distributed queries by executing following query in SSMS you will need:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Answer referenced from [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/)